# How to make arc-in animation on a website - CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am making my own website (Joomla based, but currently doing the HTML/CSS part for the template so I can't ask that in Joomla stack exchange and I thought will ask here).

[This](http://jt1337.wix.com/jtcb) is my old website, on Wix:

If you look at the bottom-right you will find the 4 links for social (Facebook, G+ etc).

Wix let me animate them nicely in an "arc-in" fashion (it's shown once when you first load/reload the page). Now I am trying to recreate the same thing using CSS but can't find any reference how such arc-in animation would be done in CSS?

I'd rather animate the element in CSS but I am open to do this in JavaScript if it would turn out too much to do in CSS. I'm a bit green in JavaScript so please explain it to me in detail how to achieve this.

Much appreciate all the help.

Comment: Take a look at [CSS3 transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read your question i was decide to goof around with css3 animations(cos i like animations) and have made a sort of what you've been asking.
Don't pretend my code to be exactly what you need but nevertheless you can play around and get what needed.

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div class="social-icons">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-5x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-5x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-5x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
</body>
```

```
.social-icons {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 35%;
        opacity: .2;
        transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.social-icons:hover {
        transform-origin: center;
        animation: rotation 3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes rotation {
        from {
                opacity: .2;
                transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(700px);
        }
        to {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
        }
}
```

The [pen](http://codepen.io/dagman/pen/BNvgbw?editors=110) itself
Hope you would like it.

Comment: No need for it to be exactly the same. I am pretty green in web developing tbh and this is my first web page project to move my graphic portfolio from Wix to some actual genuine self-made site. I was thinking that unless there's a very simple "arc-in" function of a sort I missed out, I'd need to animate it with keyframes in the way you had. Again, didn't really have much "code base" skill to start. Your answer is very helpful, Islam Ibakaev and if nobody gives a better one I will mark this as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I've ended up with something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZT1yGvM4) (just a snippet of CSS part) but ofc will adjust it more to fit my elements exactly right. I am marking your answer as solution to my question.